# Matlab: Remove fields with similar string names in a single command

Tags: string, matlab

So I have a structure, r, that contains multiple headers of the form:

Header_0001

Header_0002

Header_0003, and so on whose names are represented as strings.

Is there a way to format the strings so that I can remove these headers with a single command?

i.e.

```
r=rmfield(r,Header_00XX)
```

where X can be any number. I have tried using wildcards, anchors, etc. but have not found a method that works as of yet.

Comment: structures don't have headers. do you mean fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fields = fieldnames(r);
r = rmfield(r, fields(find(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(fields, 'Header_00')))))
```